# What should be 'the next time'?

Tags: pattern, time

A question was asked in a [mental ability test](http://www.hiqora.com/round-2) (which ended on Saturday).

> What comes next in this pattern of time:
>   **2:25**, **4:34**, **1:57**, **6:16**, ___

Note:
 1. No extra information is given like 12/24 hour time, digital or analog watch, etc.

My approach :

> "draw the time" as seen in an analog watch and calculate the angles...

Comment: Is the [mental ability test](http://www.hiqora.com/round-2) a still ongoing competition? If so, please also read this [site policy](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1675/5840)

Comment: @BmyGuest No, I know the ethical nature of Stack Exchange. The contest ended on Saturday. I felt like sharing the questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> 5:17

@Aggie Kidd found the last digit (thanks to him also for \rightarrows) and helped me find the others. A friend helped for the first digit :

> 2:25 $\rightarrow$ $ 2 + 2 = 4$ $\rightarrow$ **4**:34.
>  4:34 $\rightarrow$ $ 4 - 3 = 1$ $\rightarrow$ **1**:57.
>  1:57 $\rightarrow$ $ 1 + 5 = 6$ $\rightarrow$ **6**:16.
>  6:16 $\rightarrow$ $ 6 - 1 = 5$ $\rightarrow$ **5**:?7.

The second digit is:

> 2:25 $\rightarrow$ $ (2 + 2 + 5) \mod 6 = 3$ $\rightarrow$ 4:**3**4.
>  4:34 $\rightarrow$ $ (4 + 3 + 4) \mod 6 = 5$ $\rightarrow$ 1:**5**7.
>  1:57 $\rightarrow$ $ (1 + 5 + 7) \mod 6 = 1$ $\rightarrow$ 6:**1**6.
>  6:16 $\rightarrow$ $ (6 + 1 + 6) \mod 6 = 1$ $\rightarrow$ 5:**1**7.

Comment: Great, that's a good mathematical explanation. I'll crosscheck and reply if this was an option based question.

Answer (score 5):

Given the approach of the OP...

> and calculating all the angles on the watch (where one minute is equal to 6 degrees) I came to following values:
>
> ```
>  2:25 -> ~78°  4:34 -> ~66°   1:57 -> ~78°   6:16 -> ~90°
> ```
>
> Given this pattern I assume the next step would be -12° again, which would make it 78°
>
>  Consindering the answer of **Aggie Kidd** where the last number of the next time has to be a "7", there are 6 possible "minute positions" (7, 17, 27, 37, 47 and 57).
>
>  A time like ?:07 is not possible, since the hour hand (hope this is the right word.. I'm a non native English speaker) had to be 13 spaces behind the minute hand (which would make it point one space behind the 11 hour mark).
>
>  Same is for ?:17, ?:27, ?:37, and ?:47 since the hour hand is so close to the next hour mark that it can only be ?:57
>
>  ***So my answer is [8:57](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/34100/34131/nclock-08-57_34131_sm.gif)*** which is the only position where the hands are in a 78° angle! (might be way off though :P)

Comment: Yes, "hour hand" is correct English.

Comment: Finally,, a fellow puzzler with same answer. Yes, this was exactly my answer :)

Comment: Nice to hear that @ABcDexter. I wasn't sure about my answer after I posted this, because I'm still not 100% sold on the pattern :D

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

The time should end in:

> 7.

Because:

> **2:2**5 $\rightarrow$ $ 2 + 2 = 4$ $\rightarrow$ 4:3**4**.
>  **4:3**4 $\rightarrow$ $ 4 + 3 = 7$ $\rightarrow$ 1:5**7**.
>  **1:5**7 $\rightarrow$ $ 1 + 5 = 6$ $\rightarrow$ 6:1**6**.
>  **6:1**6 $\rightarrow$ $ 6 + 1 = 7$ $\rightarrow$ ?:?**7**.

Comment: That's a good pattern you've noted.